# Delete request giving empty reponse Express framework with Mysql

Tags: mysql, angularjs, express

I am using express to built a very basic application and i am using angular 1.2.16 , angular-resource 1.2.16 in this application i am querying Names from the database and try to delete the names req going to server but server side it says undefined and browser show error for empty reponse i tried much to figure out the problem i have used `req.body.id` and `req.query.id` but these are also not working

```js
//controller

app.controller('NameController',['$scope','$resource',function($scope,$resource)
{    var nameResource=$resource('/api/Names');

      nameResource.query(function(results)
     {
      $scope.Names=results;
     });
      $scope.Names=[];
      $scope.remove=function(id,index)
 {   
  nameResource.$delete(id); 
  console.log(id);

  
  $scope.Names.splice(index, 1);
 }


}]);

//route

app.delete('/api/Names',NamesServerController.removeEntry);


//server controller

module.exports.removeEntry=function(req, res){
 var abc=req.params.id;
 var connection=mysql.createConnection({
       host:'localhost',
       user:'root',
       password:'test123',
       database:'testing'
 });
 connection.connect();
 
 connection.query('DELETE FROM NamesTable WHERE id= ?', [req.params.id],function(err,result){
  if(err) throw err;

  
  console.log(result);
  
 });
```

```html
<div ng-controller="NameController">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat='name in Names'>
  <p> {{name.id}}</p>

  <button ng-click=remove(name.id,$index)>remove</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a response to the request. Usually a DELETE request is responded to with an empty body and a 204 status code:

```
res.send(204);
```

Comment: I try this but it still not working on server side show result zero rows effected

Comment: Apologies - I misunderstood your question. Are you certain that the mysql module is supposed to report affected rows? Have you checked in your database to see whether the rows have been deleted?